# Silverlight animation issue

Tags: silverlight, animation

Suppose I have the following XAML snippets, my confusion is what is the meaning of the value for Storyboard.TargetProperty? i.e. the meaning of "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)".

```
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="p1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" BeginTime="00:00:00">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2500000" Value="1"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

...

```
        <Path Height="2.75" Width="2.75" Data="M2.75,1.375 C2.75,2.1343915 2.1343915,2.75 1.375,2.75 C0.61560845,2.75 0,2.1343915 0,1.375 C0,0.61560845 0.61560845,0 1.375,0 C2.1343915,0 2.75,0.61560845 2.75,1.375 z" Fill="#FF9F9B9B" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="0" Canvas.Left="7" Canvas.Top="14" x:Name="p1">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
```

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

The Storyboard.TargetProperty specifies a particular property to change over time.

If you were writing it yourself, you could say something like:

```
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="myRectange"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2500000" Value="1"/>
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

and simplify things quite a bit.  In the above example, you're changing the "Width" property of your rectangle over time.  Blend, in its infinite WYSIWYG fashion, makes the targeting a little more complicated.

In your example, a transform is applied to the rectangle, and you're changing that transform over time.

Clarification:
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
is a PropertyPath.  It specifies the property that will be changed over time.  In this example, we're targeting the Rectangle's->RenderTransforms->first child (the ScaleTransform)->Scale X property.  That's how we say what's going to change.  The keyframes specify how that value changes over time.

Something to keep in mind: A transform is a static change.  Apply a ScaleX of 2, and the thing doubles in the X dimension.  But nothing changes over time (nothing moves on the screen).  For that, you need an animation to change the transform over time.

hth, Erik

Comment: Actually, my confusion is what element does " "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" refers to?